# Box2D how to determine the point when calling ApplyForce function to an object

Tags: c++, box2d

I am doing a simple shooting game using Box2D where a user will need to select an angle and a force to shoot a ball and hit something. (Something similar as Angry Birds). The initial position of my ball is static and the player could choose the angle of shooting, as well as the force. In order to do so, I am calling the `ApplyForce` function.

As referred to the documentation [here](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/api-ref/1.0/Box2D/html/classb2_body.html#aa1a2ebd027635ea5a81749f267a19261), we will need to input 2 parameters while calling `b2Body::ApplyForce(const b2Vec2 & force, const b2Vec2 & point)`. I understand what is the force for, but what is the point used for and how do I determine it?

In my case, if a user have selected a 10N force, and a 45 degrees (out of 360 degrees) shooting degree, how do I transform the 45 degree value to the `point` parameter in my code? I am not sure on how the point parameter works, and I could not find any documentation or reference to it. Any reference or guidance is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you got your understanding of the `point` parameter wrongly. The point parameter does not represent the direction of the force. Instead, you could specify the direction of the force in your `b2Vec2 force`.

If you want to apply the force to a specific degree (in your case, 45), you could do something like this.

```
yourForce = b2Vec2(cos(yourAngle) * magnitude , sin(yourAngle) * magnitude);
```

And then calling the ApplyForce function as you mentioned

```
yourObject->ApplyForce(yourForce, yourObject->GetPosition());
```